# Sending image as text in java

Tags: java, image, character-encoding, java-io

Is it possible to read image as text and send it over network? Is yes, then how can we do this?

Comment: could you give some background on the usecase: where the image originates (file/generated). What kind of process is sending the image, which transport, who's receiving it (other program,  other java program, a web browser, ...) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You could base64 encode the image to produce a (text) string.**

[Apache Commons Codec has a Base64 implementation](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) that you can easily use:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

// Read the byte array from file, DB, etc
byte[] imageByteArray = getImageByteArray();

String base64Image = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageByteArray);
```

Comment: The thing I dislike about Apache commons' Base64 is that it includes some fugly APIs, like `byte[] encodeBase64(byte[])`. In this case, the OP ended up using one of those and having problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484369/issue-with-base64-encoding-decoding-java